# JTable event Update - show error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, jtable

I would like to show error in jtabele standard event (for example alert()) but I don`t know what I have to do. Code is working correct. The most important place is if(UpdateOrNot==1){}

```
public void OnUpdated(DictionaryListModel dictionaryListModel)
        {
            var listModel = (DictionarySkillListModel)dictionaryListModel;
            if (dictionaryListModel == null)
                throw new Exception("Niepoprawny model");

            int UpdateOrNot=0;
            try
            {
            if (listModel.IsActiveYN == false)
            {
                var list =
                    _skillService.CheckSkillProcedur(listModel.Id, listModel.Description).ToList();
                foreach (var procSkillValue in list)
                {
                    UpdateOrNot = procSkillValue.ExistOrNotExist;
                }
                if(UpdateOrNot==1)
                {
                  //here I would like to past my alert
                }
                else
                {
                    var skill = _skillService.Get(listModel.Id);
                    skill.Name = listModel.Description;
                    skill.IsActive = listModel.IsActiveYN;
                    _skillService.Update(skill);
                }   
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}

        }
```

Comment: How is your question related to NHibernate? Maybe you should also write something more on what problem you experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was problem with try and catch. Fixed